# JQuery animation in for loop

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I am trying to display a short animation of products being added to a shopping cart.

I am using 3 font awesome icons. Box, Bottle and Shopping Cart.

I want the bottle to append next to the box and then move over to the shopping cart and then disappear.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  console.log(i)
  var appendItem = "<i id='movingItem" + i + "' class='fas fa-wine-bottle' style='font-size: 2em;'></i>";
  $("#animationArea").append(appendItem);
  // div = $("#movingItem");
  // console.log(i, div)
  $("#movingItem" + i).animate({
    opacity: '0.4'
  }, "slow");
  $("#movingItem" + i).animate({
    marginLeft: '300px',
    opacity: '0.8'
  }, "slow");
  $("#movingItem" + i).animate({
    opacity: '0.4'
  }, "slow");
  $("#movingItem" + i).animate({
    marginLeft: '0px',
    opacity: '0.8'
  }, "slow");
  $("#movingItem" + i).animate({
    opacity: '0'
  }, "slow");
  // $("#movingItem"+i).hide();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="testPopup" class="popup">
  <div style="width:100%;">
    <div id="animationArea" style="padding:20px 5px 20px 5px;">
      <i class="fas fa-box" style="font-size: 4em;float:left;"></i>

      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" style="font-size: 4em;float:right;"></i>
      <!-- <i class="fas fa-wine-bottle"></i> -->
    </div>

    <p id="loadingPhrase" style="text-align:center;"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, when i run my code all of the elements appear at once, what i desire is for items to be appended one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the loop with async, check the sample I have added. Or write appropriate animation css.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var i=0, n= 10; intervalTime=200;
            var intervalInstance = setInterval(function(){
                console.log(i)
                var appendItem = "<i id='movingItem" + i +
                    "' class='fas fa-wine-bottle' style='font-size: 2em;'></i>";
                $("#animationArea").append(appendItem);
                // div = $("#movingItem");
                // console.log(i, div)
                $("#movingItem" + i).animate({
                    opacity: '0.4'
                }, "slow");
                $("#movingItem" + i).animate({
                    marginLeft: '300px',
                    opacity: '0.8'
                }, "slow");
                $("#movingItem" + i).animate({
                    opacity: '0.4'
                }, "slow");
                $("#movingItem" + i).animate({
                    marginLeft: '0px',
                    opacity: '0.8'
                }, "slow");
                $("#movingItem" + i).animate({
                    opacity: '0'
                }, "slow");
                if(i+1>n){
                    clearInterval(intervalInstance)
                }
                i++;
            },intervalTime);
        })
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <div id="testPopup" class="popup">
        <div style="width:100%;">
            <div id="animationArea" style="padding:20px 5px 20px 5px;">
                <i class="fas fa-box" style="font-size: 4em;float:left;"></i>

                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" style="font-size: 4em;float:right;"></i>
                <!-- <i class="fas fa-wine-bottle"></i> -->
            </div>

            <p id="loadingPhrase" style="text-align:center;"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```